# Clang strict-aliasing optimizations vs unreachable code violating strict-aliasing

Tags: c, optimization, clang, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

I have a question about strict-aliasing and clang optimizations for one example.

Let's consider the following example (1):

```
typedef void (*FTy)(void);
FTy F = 0;
(*F)();
```

It is an undefined behavior.

Let's consider the example (2) below:

```
typedef void (*FTy)(void);
static const FTy F = 0;

void g( int flag)
{
    if ( flag )
    {
        (*F)();
    }
}

int main( void)
{
    g( 0);
    return (0);
}
```

Indirect call by F is still "undefined behavior", but stands under always false condtion. So programm must be correct.

Now let's consider the main example (3):
(second edition: Thanks to @Antti Haapala simplified version)
(third edition: using of always_inline)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef BUGGY
#define BUGGY 1
#endif

static inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) longLongAssign( int cond, char *ptr)
{
    if ( cond )
    {
        *((long long *)ptr) = 0;
    }
}

void funcA(int s, int g)
{
    int i, j = 0, k;
    int grp[4] = {-1, -1};
    void *ptr[2] = {(void *)&(grp[0]), 0};

    for (i = 0, k = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
            if ( grp[g] > 0 )
            {
                if ( g > 5 )
                {
                    continue;

                } else
                {
                    longLongAssign( g > 3, (char *)ptr[0]);
                }
            }
            grp[k++] = 0;
        }
        printf("this should be zero: %d\n", grp[0]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    funcA(0, 1);
}
```

Compile by gcc and execute

```
this should be zero: 0
```

Compile by "clang-7.0 -O0" and execute

```
this should be zero: 0
```

Compile by "clang-7.0 -O1 -fno-strict-aliasing" and execute

```
this should be zero: 0
```

Compile by "clang-7.0 -O1" and execute

```
this should be zero: -1
```

In the main example one of stores to grp formally violates strict-aliasing

```
        *((long long *)ptr) = 0;
```

But this store stands under always false condition.

The question here is: how a store operation

- violating breaking strict-aliasing rule
- but located in unreachable statement

may affect any way to program execution?

Is it correct by C language standart?

Is an example (4) below correct, well defined and hasn't undefined behavior?

```
void assign( int type, char *ptr)
{
    if ( ptr )
    {
        if ( (type == 0) )
        {
            *((int *)ptr) = 1;

        } else if ( (type == 1) )
        {
            *((float *)ptr) = 1;
        } else
        {
            // unknown type
        }
     }
 }

 int main( void)
 {
     int a;
     float b;

     assign( 0, (char *)&a);
     assign( 1, (char *)&b);
     assign( 0, (char *)0);

     return (0);
 }
```

Inline and constant propagation optimizations in function main gives

```
    ...
    if ( &a )
    {
        if ( (0 == 0) )
        {
            *((int *)&a) = 1;

        } else if ( (0 == 1) )
        {
            *((float *)&a) = 1;
        } else
        {
            // unknown type
        }
    }
    ...
```

In one hand store operation

```
            *((float *)&a) = 1;
```

formally violates strict-aliasing, but stands in unreacheble location.

Which reasons example (4) may be incorrect?
If example (4) is correct so why example (3) gives by clang compilation different results?

Comment: "3 A program that is correct in all other aspects, operating on correct data, containing unspecified behavior shall be a correct program and act in accordance with 5.1.2.3."... it is not said anywhere that a program containing **undefined** behaviour is a correct program.

Comment: Surely the main example can be simplified to something more easily manageable while still expressing the relevant details.

Comment: In fact, as presented, the code has structures and characteristics that seem intended specifically to obfuscate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess, the program is a stripped down variant of something bigger and written in this way to provide a MCVE

Comment: Is the `longjmp` essential to the bug? I don't have Clang 7.1...

Comment: Yes, the test was extracted and simplified as possible from one real project . (The project was obfuscated.)

Comment: But that's just the point, @ensc: it is *not* an MCVE, or at least it doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: I got -1, -1 in Clang 6.0, so at least reproducible.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is a) minimal, b) complete, c) verificable and d) an example.  So why do you think it is not an MCVE?

Comment: I've removed the `while` after the function pointer call, and it didn't have any effect...

Comment: @ensc So this is not **minimal**. I've got the behaviour with clang 6.0.0 and removing the while loop, function *pointer* dereference, etc...

Comment: `longjmp` is not needed either.

Comment: @ensc, it should be possible also to reduce the single-trip loops to linear code, to remove the conditional compilation directives, and possibly more.  If removing any of that affects the observed behavior, then it is important for the OP to call specific attention to that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  true; sorry.  I was focused on the `sigjmp()` but it can be reproduced with much less and more simple code indead.

Comment: @Павел do you agree that [this code](https://gist.github.com/ztane/ed60a0cf8b4fba4a318cabacfae493b6) reproduces the problem - it is much more a [mcve] and does focus more on the actual problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the loops seemed to be essential... also the array needed 4 elements as opposed to say 2...

Comment: All important information to be conveyed in the question, @AnttiHaapala, so that you and I don't need to perform the exercise that you just did.

Comment: Thank you @Antti Haapala, your code is more better

Comment: @Павел but do you concur that it still reproduces the problem - if you can verify it yourself using your GCC, Clang, and if it does then please [edit] this question to contain it - and for posterity, this is an exercise that *you* as the question author should do.

Comment: @Павел I am still waiting for your reply ... and action...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I modified the question. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

The expression statement

> ```
>                     *(long long *)grp = 0;
> ```

has undefined behavior on account of accessing an object of type `int[4]` via an lvalue of different, incompatible type (`long long`) -- a strict-aliasing violation, as you observe in the question.  But that doesn't have to be limited to *runtime* behavior. The (potential) issue being visible at translation time, the translation-time behavior is undefined, too, and therefore so is the result of every execution.

Or at minimum, that's an interpretation of the standard to which at least some compiler developers subscribe.  Some folks around here object to such interpretations, but that doesn't change the fact that you have to deal with them.

**With regard to the update**

Your example (4) has perfectly well-defined behavior.  The major considerations here are

- It is explicitly permitted to convert a value of one object-pointer type to a different object-pointer type.  There are caveats about alignment of the result, but C requires it always to work for conversion to `char *`, and it requires the reverse conversion to reproduce the original pointer value (which has no alignment issue if it was valid to begin with).
- It is permitted to access any object's representation via an lvalue of character type.  In other words, a `char *` is permitted to alias any part of any object, so even though you *don't* access anything directly through the `char *` values passed to `assign()`, a conforming compiler must assume that those pointers could alias any object in the program.
- A null pointer of any type can be converted to another object-pointer type, resulting in a null pointer of the target type.
- By use of the `type` argument to function `assign()` in a manner consistent with that function's implementation, the program ensures that each object involved is ultimately accessed (only) via an lvalue of its correct type.

What optimizations the compiler might apply are irrelevant to this analysis.  It is the code you present to the compiler by which behavior, if defined, is established.  Supposing that the program has defined behavior, it is the *compiler's* responsibility to ensure that that behavior is exhibited by the program resulting from translation to an executable, and it may and does use its knowledge about its own implementation to provide for that.

Comment: Added an example (4) with "issue being visible at translation time". @JohnBollinger, may you to comment this example?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly why example (4) is significant, it not appearing to be meaningfully related to any of the others.  But I have added some commentary about it.

Comment: By example (4) I want to model situation with "formal violation of strict-aliasing" in "unreachable statement location", I suppose both examples are equivalent modulo this property.

Comment: Thus, if example (4) is valid, than example (3) is valid too.

Comment: I modified example (3) to use longLongAssign function.

Comment: Example (4) has no strict-aliasing violation, as I have already explained.

Comment: Example (3) *does* (still) contain a strict-aliasing violation, therefore its behavior is undefined.  In particular, accessing an `int[4]` via an lvalue of type `long long` has undefined behavior regardless of the circumstances or whether the compiler can be expected to recognize it.

Comment: Argument "ptr" of function longLongAssing has type "char *", condition "cond" is always false. That is why I suppose example (3) now doesn't violate strict-aliasing rule. Last version of example (3) is identical to example (4), isn't it?

Comment: @Павел, all of your followups have been variations on the same theme already presented in the question and answered here.  Although it may be that you can form a plausible argument for some alternative along these lines to avoid UB, what ultimately matters is what the *compiler* thinks.  You are best off avoiding code that compiler is at risk of interpreting as having UB, whether you think that would be a correct interpretation or not.  You happen to be exploring an area that is particularly open to varying interpretation, which is unwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments! You've helped me to understand the problem much better.

Just to clarify why I do this and what I really wanted:
I am porting clang on some specific platform. So my goal here was to understand if this test (from our autogen test system) contains error, or rather it's clang compilation bug. On results of this discussion, I've submitted an llvm bug
(https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41178).

Thanks again!